# Oracle APEX error ORA-01460 ORA-02063

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I am creating a Classic Report (based on Function) with the following code:

```
declare
    q long;
begin
-- The query with any conditions always applied
    q := 'select * from name_selection_atnd where 1 = 1';

-- If all items are null then kill query
if  :P500_FN is null 
    and :P500_LN is null
then
    q := q || ' and name_said = 0'; --will always return 0 rows
end if;

-- Append any optional conditions
if :P500_FN is not null then
  q := q || ' and name_first_name = :P500_FN';
end if;

if :P500_LN is not null then
  q := q || ' and name_last_name = :P500_LN';
end if;

return q;
end;
```

My final code will need to contain more items to search besides first and last name but for now I am testing with just these two parameters. When I only fill in a first name, the search works. When I only fill in a last name, it works. When I type in a first AND last name I get the error ORA-01460 and ORA-02063.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: What are you entering for`P500_FN`. why are you using bind variable everywhere. Use only once in declare to get the value from bind variable into a local variable. do comparisons on those variables.

Comment: I am typing a string. Just a person's first name

Comment: Can you give the full error messages rather than just the codes?

Comment: report error:
ORA-01460: unimplemented or unreasonable conversion requested
ORA-02063: preceding line from JHS_ATND

Comment: What is `JHS_ATND`?

Comment: JHS_ATND is my username. But it is also my schema name. I am selecting data from a view that uses database links. The view loads fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see that you used `bind` variables inside `''` which would be never evaluated in a PLSQL block:

```
q := q || ' and name_first_name = :P500_FN';
```

This should be like this :

```
q := q || ' and name_first_name = '||:P500_FN;
```

Comment: Great! But now if I type in a name like 'Jordan' I get this error ORA-00904: "JORDAN": invalid identifier

Comment: @JordanHolmer You need to pass `Jordan` as a string so it must be in `'Jordan'` when you pass it. you must include single quotes(') when you pass values.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need dynamic SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM   name_selection_atnd
WHERE  ( :P500_FN IS NULL OR name_first_name = :P500_FN )
AND    ( :P500_LN IS NULL OR name_last_name  = :P500_LN )
AND    ( :P500_FN IS NOT NULL OR :P500_LN IS NOT NULL );
```